# button not functioning?

Tags: android

I created a android studio button for my app and when I click on the register button it doesn't work . I don't get any errors it just doesn't work . When the user clicks the quiz button I want to go to the quiz activity

MainActivity.java

```
package com.littlekidsmath.yoong.mathlearningforkids;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements         View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Button addBtn, subBtn, multiBtn, divisionBtn,quiz;
String[] levels = {"Easy","Medium","Hard"};
SharedPreferences prefs;
Switch settings;
Spinner language;
public String[] languages = {GameActivity.ENG,GameActivity.ARABIC,"বাংলা",GameActivity.FRENCH,GameActivity.GERMAN,GameActivity.MALAY};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    settings = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.settings);

    if(prefs.getBoolean("SOUND", false)){
        settings.setChecked(true);
    }

    settings.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            prefs.edit().putBoolean("SOUND",b).commit();

        }
    });

    addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtion);
    subBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    multiBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multi);
    divisionBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
    quiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quiz);
    language = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.language);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    subBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    multiBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    divisionBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    quiz.setOnClickListener(this);
    language.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
    language.setAdapter(adapter);
    int pos = 0;
//
    for(int i=0;i<languages.length;i++){
        if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(languages[i])){
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    language.setSelection(pos);
    if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.BANGLA)){
        setBangla();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.ARABIC)){
        setArabic();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.FRENCH)){
        setFrence();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.GERMAN)){
        setGerman();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.ENG)){
        setEnglish();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.MALAY)){
        setMalay();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addtion: {
            levelChooseDialog("+");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.sub: {
            levelChooseDialog("-");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.multi: {
            levelChooseDialog("X");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.divide: {
            levelChooseDialog("/");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.quiz: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

}





public void levelChooseDialog(final String operator){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = View.inflate(this,R.layout.level_dialog,null);
    builder.setView(view);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,levels);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int level = 0;

            if (position == 0){
                level = 0;
            }else if(position == 1){
                level = 1;
            }else {
                level = 2;
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LessonActivity.class).putExtra("level",level)
            .putExtra("operator",operator));
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    prefs.edit().putString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,languages[position]).commit();

    if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.BANGLA))
{
        setBangla();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.ARABIC)){
        setArabic();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.FRENCH)){
        setFrence();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.GERMAN)){
        setGerman();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.ENG)){
        setEnglish();
    }else if(prefs.getString(GameActivity.LANGUAGE,"").equals(GameActivity.MALAY)){
        setMalay();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void setBangla(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.BANGLA[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.BANGLA[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.BANGLA[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.BANGLA[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.BANGLA[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.BANGLA[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.BANGLA[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.BANGLA[9];
}

public void setArabic(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.ARABIC[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.ARABIC[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.ARABIC[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.ARABIC[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.ARABIC[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.ARABIC[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.ARABIC[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.ARABIC[9];
}

public void setMalay(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.MALAY[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.MALAY[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.MALAY[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.MALAY[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.MALAY[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.MALAY[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.MALAY[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.MALAY[9];
}

public void setFrence(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.FRENCH[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.FRENCH[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.FRENCH[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.FRENCH[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.FRENCH[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.FRENCH[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.FRENCH[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.FRENCH[9];
}

public void setGerman(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.GERMAN[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.GERMAN[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.GERMAN[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.GERMAN[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.GERMAN[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.GERMAN[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.GERMAN[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.GERMAN[9];
}

public void setEnglish(){
    addBtn.setText(Languages.ENGLISH[0]);
    subBtn.setText(Languages.ENGLISH[1]);
    multiBtn.setText(Languages.ENGLISH[3]);
    divisionBtn.setText(Languages.ENGLISH[2]);
    settings.setText(Languages.ENGLISH[4]);

    levels[0] = Languages.ENGLISH[7];
    levels[1] = Languages.ENGLISH[8];
    levels[2] = Languages.ENGLISH[9];
}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.littlekidsmath.yoong.mathlearningforkids.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/add"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Addition" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/minus"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Subtraction" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/cancel"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Multiplication" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/division"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Division" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/quiz"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="Quiz" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Sound"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="Language" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/language"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help please? When click on the quiz button the application will close. I want it to go to quiz page which called HomeScreen.java

Comment: If your application is closed when you click on quiz button, button listener is perfectly working. Have you declare HomeScreen activity on the manifest file? It seems the most probable cause

Comment: The other option might be that you didnt use setContentView in onCreate inside the acitivitiy you are trying to start.

Comment: What that means is your button is working fine. You are having trouble while opening the HomeScreen. You need to share your homescreen code as well. And I am certain that your app is throwing some exceptions, either you did not look at right place or your code swallows it. Find and share the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

looks good to me, did u declare the second activity in the manifest file? :

```
<activity android:name="HomeScreen"/>
```

If that doesn't work, use some break points and the debugger, hope it helps.

Comment: Use a Toast to check if the click button event is working (before the intent creation):

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

If the toast is displayed, it might be a problem in your seconds activity, probably in the onCreate method, like not calling the setContentView, etc